# Auto Play Doesn't worked in audio element

Tags: html, html5-audio

I tried using the `autoplay` attribute in the audio element by using the `<source>` and `<audio>` tags as in the following code

```html
<audio autoplay controls>
    <source src="media/Download Free Waves Sound Effects.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

It's not auto-playing the audio. I tried using MS Edge and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **absolute path** for audio file instead of using relative file.

Note: The path with reference to root directory is called absolute. The path with reference to current directory is called relative.

Comment: thanks I know what was the error   Autoplay setting was disabled in my browser